# MissingMethodException No signature of method: java.lang.String.collectReplacements()

Tags: string, groovy

I need to write a little code in groovy that replaces non-digit characters in string

i have written sth like this based on stuff in the net

```
def sx = "00OOoo00"

def replacement = {
    if (it == 'O'){
        '0'
    } else if (it == 'o') {
        '0'
    } else {
        null
    }
}   

sx.collectReplacements(replacement)     

println sx
```

But compiler throws an error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.collectReplacements() is applicable for argument types: (ConsoleScript23$_run_closure1) values: [ConsoleScript23$_run_closure1@3bd2ab63]
```

Thanks in advance for response

Comment: Please try to include a language in your tags, you will get more attention to the question then.. and by relevant users. I have added "java" for you

Comment: Works for me with Groovy 2.2.1

Comment: @Cebence No, otherwise every JVM language question will end up tagged as java

Comment: I *believe* `String.collectReplacements` was added to Groovy 2.1.0, so I assume you're using an older version of Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

This is not realy groovy, but in groovy you always can use the java functionalities:

```
sx = sx.replaceAll("o", "0").replaceAll("O", "0")
```

For this simple task you dont need a closure imho